# How to add optional validation to form fields using reactive forms in angular 8?

Tags: angular8

```
air: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.pattern('^[0-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{1,3}|)$')]),
seaFCL: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{1,3}|)$'), Validators.maxLength(5)]),
seaLCL: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{1,3}|)$'), Validators.maxLength(5)]),
```

These are 2 fields, `air` and `sea` (has 2 sub fields `LCL` and `FCL` but I have coded both under `sea`). I'm stuck up as I need to either have one of them filled while validating. Both are not needed together to be validated. One of the fields needs to filled.